# Recursive function that creates an array from 0 to n (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, recursion

I've been reading a lot about recursive functions recently though I wasn't able to figure this one out until today. I think I now understand recursion better. Hopefully I can help someone else who is still struggeling with it:

```
function count(n) {
    if (n === 1) {
      return [1];
    } else {
      var numbers = count(n - 1); 
      numbers.push(n); 
      return numbers; 
    }
  }

console.log(count(3));
```

The result of `count(3)` will be: `[1, 2, 3]`

Comment: btw, you need no else, because of the return statement of the truthy statement part (statement1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We pass in 3 into `count(n)`. Since n is not equal to 1 we go straight to the else statement. `numbers = count(3 - n)` or `numbers = count(2)` if we pass in n. What happens next is recursion:

Since we don't know what exactly `count(2)` is we have to run it to figure out. So we run `count(2)`. n is not equal to 1 so we go to the else statement again. `numbers = count(1)`. Recursion again. We put in 1 for n and this time the function returns `[1]`. 
Now since we know that `count(1) = [1]` we are able to solve `count(2)`. `count(2)` is `numbers = count(1)` or `numbers = [1]`. This time we go ahead in our code and push in n `numbers.push(n)` which is 2. So `count(2)` returns `[1, 2]`. Now since we know the result for `count(2)` let's solve `count(3)`. `count(3)` is `numbers = count(2)` or `numbers = [1, 2]` putting in our result. Now push gets activated and voila, our result for `count(3)` is `[1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: `count(0)` and voila.